# How to choose camera for qrscan

Tags: html, api, camera

What is the best strategy to choose camera for qrcode scanning?
Currently modern devices have few back cameras.
For example huawei mate 20 have 4 camera (3 physical and 1 virtual based on physical ones)
Currently my algorithm just selecting first camera with "back" in label.
Is there any better strategy for best readability of qr code?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
this.qrScannerComponent.getMediaDevices().then(devices => {
  // this.info = devices.map((dev, i) => `${i}. ${dev.label}`).join('\n');

  const videoDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[] = [];
  for (const device of devices) {
    if (device.kind.toString() === 'videoinput') {
        videoDevices.push(device);
    }
  }
  if (videoDevices.length > 0) {
    let choosenDev;
    for (const dev of videoDevices) {
      if (dev.label.includes('back')) {
        choosenDev = dev;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (choosenDev) {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(choosenDev);
    } else {
      this.qrScannerComponent.chooseCamera.next(videoDevices[0]);
    }
  }
});
```